# How do I get subtree to pull source into directory without creating a patent directory?

Tags: git, git-pull, git-subtree

I am trying to add a plugin repository as a git-subtree, but instead of pulling the code into the Plugins folder, it insists on creating an extraneous parent folder with the same name.

```
$ git subtree add --prefix=src/Plugins/Nop.Plugin.Payments.PurchaseOrder purchase-order-plugin nopcommerce-4.10 --squash -d
command: {add}
quiet: {}
revs: {}
dir: {src/Plugins/Nop.Plugin.Payments.PurchaseOrder}
opts: {purchase-order-plugin nopcommerce-4.10}

git fetch purchase-order-plugin nopcommerce-4.10
From https://github.com/nopSolutions/purchaseorder-plugin-for-nopcommerce
 * branch                nopcommerce-4.10 -> FETCH_HEAD
Adding src/Plugins/Nop.Plugin.Payments.PurchaseOrder as '47e8ba8be0b300dffbd335d42c222e9af3c3b14f'...
Added dir 'src/Plugins/Nop.Plugin.Payments.PurchaseOrder'
```

[image]

I've tried every imaginable UNIXish pathname. How do I undo this disaster and get it to pull the source without the parent.

This kind of reminds me of zip utilities where you have no idea wether it will unzip them into a folder, nest inside another folder with the same name, or spew files all over all over the place, turning your directory into a brownfield cleanup project.

Comment: Hmmm.  I guess emporer Git wears no clothes!  We have all these uber techies pushing this stuff on us and it can't handle simple subprojects--a major requirement for any serious source control.  When will this yucky Git tyranny end?